# How to add like match against Product attribute select option labels in Magento EE

Tags: magento

I need to add like keyword match against Product attribute(Color, Manufacturer ... 23 attributes which is all select drop down type) select option labels in Magento EE with 'or', 'and' conditions.

Though I already Searched and found some solutions and different methods to get result for this, i couldn't find the reason why its not working for me.

I have added rewrite class to add the above filter options

```
/*
 * Rewritten to add Match all|any filtering
 */
protected function _getProductCollection()
{
    if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
        $keyword = $this->getRequest()->getParam('keyword', '');
        $filterOption = $this->getRequest()->getParam('fo', '');
        $this->_productCollection = parent::_getProductCollection();
        if ($filterOption != '' && $keyword != '') {
            $filterableAttributesArray = $this->getFilterableAttributes();//Got all filterable select dropdown attributes with its attribute_id
            if ($filterableAttributesArray && count($filterableAttributesArray)) {
                $filterables = array();
                foreach ($filterableAttributesArray as $attr) {
                    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToSelect($attr);
                    $filterables[] = array('attribute' => $attr, 'like' => '%' . "$keyword" . '%');
                }
                if ($filterOption == 'any') {
                    $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($filterables);
                } else {
                    foreach ($filterables as $attr_cond) {
                        $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter($attr_cond);
                    }
                }
                $this->_productCollection->load();
            }
        }
        d((string)$this->_productCollection->getSelect());
    }
    return $this->_productCollection;
}
```

Query for this coming as 
**For 'or' Condition**

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_color`.`value` AS `color`, `at_manufacturer`.`value` AS `manufacturer` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_color` ON (`at_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_color`.`attribute_id` = '92') AND (`at_color`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '81') AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0)
```

**WHERE ((at_color.value LIKE '%blue%') OR (at_manufacturer.value LIKE '%blue%'))**

**For 'and' condition**

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, `at_color`.`value` AS `color`, `at_manufacturer`.`value` AS `manufacturer` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id = '3'
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1' AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_color` ON (`at_color`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_color`.`attribute_id` = '92') AND (`at_color`.`store_id` = 0)
 INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_manufacturer` ON (`at_manufacturer`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_manufacturer`.`attribute_id` = '81') AND (`at_manufacturer`.`store_id` = 0)
```

**WHERE ((at_color.value LIKE '') AND (at_manufacturer.value LIKE ''))**

*Its Magento Enterprise Edition 1.13.1.0*

This doesn't give me the results - since its not matching against the attribute option label instead its option_id How can I solve this?